# continuous print of button Pushed

Tags: arduino-uno

When pushing a button I want to read the value...once.
If I push(hold) the button I get a continuous print of button1Pushed

```
    if(button1State == LOW) { 
     Serial.println("button1Pushed");
  }
```

But if I try to solve it like this, nothing happens, not a single print. What am I missing?

```
 int button1State = digitalRead(button1);
  int lastButton1State;
  
  if(button1State != lastButton1State){
      if(button1State == LOW){
        Serial.println("button1Pushed");
               }
        }

  lastButton1State = button1State;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastButton1State` is not initialized and therefore has no strictly defined value. In your case, it appears to have a value of `0` (which is random, it's not due to implicit initialization, which is only done for global variables). The condition `if(button1State != lastButton1State)` becomes true only if the button is released.

You can check that by changing

```
if(button1State == LOW){
  Serial.println("button1Pushed");
}
```

to

```
if(button1State == HIGH){
  Serial.println("button1 released");
}
```

The following should work:

```
int last_button_state=HIGH; // initialize to HIGH, so the button does not teigger on very first iteration
void setup () {
  // whatever you want to do here
}
void loop() {
  int button_state=digitalRead(button1);
  if (button_state!=last_button_state && button_state==LOW) {
    Serial.println("button pressed");
  }
  else if (button_state!=last_button_state && button_state==HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button released");
  }
  last_button_state=button_state;
}
```

Comment: your suggestion gives me the same result, still an endless repeat of the serial.print

Comment: Did you see the change I made? I forgot to add `last_button_state=button_state;`... if it still doesn't work, please post the entire code

Comment: I tried your suggestion in a blank sketch and it works!
There is probably something buggy in the rest of my code (its pretty huge..for me..as a amateur)

Comment: Found it! I put int last_button_state=HIGH; in the loop.....pff..time for bed

Comment: @Niles please see my comment